# Java multithreading without happens-before relationship

Tags: java, multithreading, happens-before

I have two threads using the same `Object obj` and as I have read every change made in `obj` by `Thread A` will be visible for `Thread B` due to happens-before relationship.

What I want to do is the opposite, changing `obj` in `Thread A` without being visible from `Thread B` but I have no clue about how to do that.

I have tried creating a `ThreadLocal` in `Thread B`, setting it in `run()` method, and using `ThreadLocal.get()` instead of `obj` in `Thread B` but it keeps reading the changes.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** (MVCE)

```
public class MyThreadLocal {

    public static final ThreadLocal<Email> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Email>();

    public static void set(Email email) {
        threadLocal.set(email);
    }

    public static void remove() {
        threadLocal.remove();
    }

    public static Email get() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }
}
```

Main Thread

```
serviceEnvioTaskSpring.setThreadName(getIdInstanciaOrigen());   //serviceEnvioTaskSpring is an instance of a class which implements Runnable    

//set some more class' attributes

serviceEnvioTaskSpring.setEmail(email); //email is the shared object

ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

threadExecutor.execute(serviceEnvioTaskSpring);

threadExecutor.shutdown();
```

Thread B

```
public void run() {
    try {

        //a few business logic lines

        MyThreadLocal.set(email);
        this.performTask();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error( "Error al lanzar thread asincrono: "+ e.getMessage()+" - "+e.getCause() );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void performTask() {
    //do stuff in a for loop accessing email with MyThreadLocal.get();      
}
```

The issue happens when I keep running the main thread since its next step is refreshing the whole page so `email` is set to a new instance, which makes me lose MyThreadLocal's email information

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: So you need two separate objects for the two different threads. Or why would you want to have a shared object but without the changes being visible to the other thread?

Comment: happens-before has nothing to do with this. You are basically modifying the same object/reference from different threads

Comment: @ZaidAmir not really. A `ThreadLocal` is normally used to provide each `Thread` with its own instance of some type, i.e. to prevent sharing data. But without a MCVE, we are unable to help.

Comment: @Persixty here is it, sorry about not posting it at the first time, I was trying to do more a theoretical question

Comment: @Turing85 here is it, sorry about not posting it at the first time, I was trying to do more a theoretical question

Comment: Assuming `performTask()` (or any other thread) modifies `email` you will (or may..) see changes made by other threads to `email` depending on synchronization of said email. You don't make a local copy of email, you make a local reference to it. I also have no idea why you'd make email thread-local when the answer is (and normally is) to make it an instance variable of `Runnable`. That largely amounts to the same thing and you only use `ThreadLocal` for implementation details you don't expose to the wider application (and very rarely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have two threads using the same Object obj and as I have read every change made in obj by Thread A will be visible for Thread B due to happens-before relationship.

That's not correct.  Or at least ... it is not correct *as you have written it*<sup>1</sup>.

The reality is that a *happens-before* relationship guarantees that updates will be visible.  If there is no *happens-before* relationship, then the changes might be visible ... or they might be NOT visible.

> What I want to do is the opposite, changing obj in Thread A without being visible from Thread B but I have no clue about how to do that.

Basically, you *cannot* guarantee it.  If two threads are looking at the same object, then there is no way to STOP one thread from seeing changes by the other.

Using thread-local variables doesn't help.

If you want one thread to not see the changes made to an object by the other thread, then you need to copy or clone the object and have the two threads use different copies.

---

<sup>1 - (What you wrote implies that a change made by A will *always* be visible to B because there is a *happens-before* relationship.  But there isn't necessarily a *happens-before* relationship!  I will grant that you may not have *meant* that ... but I don't *know* that you didn't mean it, which is why I am being pedantic.)</sup>